# Java string split with tabs

Tags: java

Given that `string` is a `String`, what does `string.split("[\t]");` do? I don't understand what the brackets are for. Thanks!

Comment: Read the method javadoc. And follow the clues (regex!).

Comment: (Also known as a "character class" in the appropriate context. There is no need for them in this case, as `"\t"` would have been equivalent, but maybe it was/will be `"[\t-]"` or something else..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as `string.split("\\t");` but I guess some people find it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

`string.split("[\t]");` will split the string into an array of strings with a Tab being the separating character. The brackets are for defining a construct regex pattern or a character class, and with only one character they're actually not needed.
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) is an example